# Where joomla stores Page Heading? in DB? What table?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I cannot find where in DB joomla stores the Page Heading from 
Menu manager>Menu Items>some menu>page display options>page heading

Comment: Close voted, for not enough efforts to search online, or trying yourself ....

Comment: Still didnt find it in DB, but found a workaround in case someone will need it:

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menus = $app->getMenu();
$menu = $menus->getActive();
echo $menu->params->get('page_heading');
Thanks Mr.Alien for making me google more :-)

Comment: And that code tells you exactly where it is, in the menus table params field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla stores "page heading" in menu table and field name is `params`.

Comment: @EliasMamo it's Ajay who answered the question and not Valentin, also if this helped, than mark the answer as correct so it will help future visitors to refer